# How to deploy Yolean Kubernetes Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, kubernetes

repo: [yolean/kubernetes-kafka](https://github.com/Yolean/kubernetes-kafka)

I'm going to follow the steps to deploy a kafka cluster in the cloud. But I don't quite understand the instruction.  Specifically, under /kafka and /zookeeper, do I need to "kubectl create -f" all YAMLs? what do the numerical prefix of each YAML represent? And what order do I need to follow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to "kubectl create -f" all YAMLs?

If you want a fully installed cluster, yes.

> what do the numerical prefix of each YAML represent?

Ordering. For example, configure the broker pods, then install Kafka, then configure Kafka

> And in what order I need to follow?

Ascending order. Zookeeper before Kafka